# Cannot compile or run code in Code::Blocks 12.11

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have downloaded Code:Blocks with MinGW, trying to get some C++ going.  After installing, opening, and creating a console application, I have been unable to run the "Hello World" main.cpp that it instantiates. I have numerous problems.

There are red lines under "Hello" and "World" as if the compiler does not recognize them.

The first thing I did was install Code:Blocks without MinGW and it popped up showing my compilers, the only one was VS C++ 2010.  Now uninstalling it and re-installing it does not allow that dialog to pop-up again.

When I first start Code:Blocks it used to say it couldn't find mspdb100.dll.

When I try to run the program it tells me it needs to build.  I build it, it tells me it needs to build again...  Then some console windows pop up and disappear, too quickly to read.  The Build Log outputs "Process terminated with status 1104 (0 minutes, 0 seconds).  0 errors, 0 warnings.

Code by request:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The internet hasn't helped me much.  Can stackoverflow?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please include your code too?

Comment: I know it will be a bit tricky to get it running without MinGW, anyways if you switched to the version including MinGW should be absolutely out of the box, is this the one you're using? http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/12.11/Windows/codeblocks-12.11mingw-setup.exe/download

Comment: Yes that's what I used.  Originally I downloaded codeblocks-12.11-setup.exe, uninstalled, and installed the one you mention.

Comment: Ok, it might be related to the previous installation then, but if the select compiler dialog didn't appear during the later install, am sure there is an option inside the IDE to select the correct one. Also, if your window closes so fast, have you tried debugging it?

Comment: So my lack of experience with C++ cannot be overstated.  Should have said that up front.  I am running it in Debug mode, I am not sure exactly what you mean by "debugging".  I have selected a compiler by going to settings -> Compiler and picking the GNU GCC Compiler which it detects in the right location.  However with this compiler selected (as opposed to VS C++ 2010) when starting I get the error mentioned above "The program can't start because mspdb100.dll is missing from your computer.  Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

Comment: Okay so I clicked "Debug" instead of "Run", gotcha.  The only output that is particularly noticeable is the line "Starting the debuggee failed: No executable specified, use 'target exec'."  Any clues from that?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I think there are multiple possibilities. We can all agree that you code looks fine.
The problem lies here:

```
cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
return 0;
```

You say, that it puts red lines under `Hello` and `world!`. Some characters might look like each other, for example “, ” and ". Therefore, open your file with the hex editor, and make sure that the `"` is represented by `22`.
You open the hex editor by navigating to the "Files" tab under the management tool window, then right clicking on your file and select "Open with Hex editor".

Then, you mention the problem with the window that opens / closes too fast. There are two solutions:

1. Add the line `cin.get();` between the hello world-line and the return-line.
   This pauses your application until you press enter.
2. Go to Project > Properties... > Build targets and check the "Pause when execution ends". Make sure that the combobox above is set to "Console application".

Comment: " is represented by 22. When I add 1 nothing seems to change, the console window still closes.  The settings in 2 were already set.

Comment: @KyleWright: Very strange. Are you able to upload the whole project someplace, or can you eventually try to run it on another machine. If you are on Windows, try to install [Visual c++ runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555)

Comment: I actually have "A newer version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable".  I will try to use a different machine.